# view Large PDF file in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, file, pdf, view

I have followed some tutorial that teach me how to view PDF file in UIWebView, however I found that if the file size is large, it will be lag when I zoom the PDF, but it doesn't occur in Mobile Safari.

So anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly - there is no simple way to speed up the browsing of large PDF documents. The solution used most commonly is to split the document in smaller chunks (typically, pages) and load each one separately.